# Not able to create Scratch Org in VS Code

Tags: vs-code

I am trying to create a scratch org from VS code but it shows me an error. It says "connect ETIMEDOUT 101.53.168.237:443"

I was able to do it correctly few days back - all of a sudden its not allowing me to do now.. What could be the reason?

Screenshot:

[image]

I can able to open Default Org with this comment though!

> sfdx force:org:open

Comment: Just a guess, check out your internet connection, i saw this error message very often when i am running out of good internet.

Comment: My internet connection is good - I can access other websites quickly.. However VS Code is not working - However, I tried to connect from my mobile network and it works fine.. I guess It has something to do with my Wifi. any guess?